# gopher wood / coffer

Tags: etymology

I am trying to find out if there is any connection between 'gopher' wood, the wood from which Noah is supposed to have built his ark and 'coffer', in the sense of a strong wooden chest. Gopher seems to be derived from 'kophein' the Greek for basket and an ark is also a strong box as in the ark of the covenant ('arca', 'arcere' etc.). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Probably not, according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gopher&allowed_in_frame=0):

> The
>    gopherwood tree of the Bible (used by Noah to
>   make the ark, Gen. vi:14) is ... from
>   Heb. gofer, perhaps meaning the cypress.

And:

> coffer (n.) mid-13c., from Old French cofre "a chest" (12c.,
>   Modern French coffre), from Latin cophinus
>   "basket" (see coffin).